# Invalid Component definition when trying to register my component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I can't get my components to work in Vue CLI. My file structure is as follows

[image]

I'm trying to use `GameHub` and `GamesAdmin` as components like so:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <game-admin v-if="user.admin == 1"></game-admin>
        <game-hub v-else></game-hub>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { gameAdmin } from '../components/GamesAdmin';
import { gameHub } from '../components/GameHub';
export default {
    data(){
        return{
        }
    },
    components: {
        gameAdmin : 'gameAdmin',
        gameHub : 'gameHub'
    },
    props:[
        'user',
    ],
}
</script>
```

However, I get this error:

[image]

And I can't seem to figure out what is wrong here?

Comment: [naming conventions are important in vue](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-name-casing-in-JS-JSX-strongly-recommended). make sure that you're adhering to  convention that is a.) supported and b.) easy to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're registering the local components as strings, rather than using the objects you've imported from the component files.

Change your `components` definition to:

```js
components: {
  gameAdmin : gameAdmin,
  gameHub : gameHub
}
```

-or- to the equivalent with [es2015 shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015)

```js
components: {
  gameAdmin
  gameHub
}
```

Also, components need to be the `default` export from your `.vue` file, so your imports probably need to be changed also, to use default import syntax rather than named import syntax:

```js
import gameAdmin from '../components/GamesAdmin';
import gameHub from '../components/GameHub';
```

Comment: Yup, that was it, I thought curled braces just meant multiple components or like an array of components, of course I didn't need that here but I also thought they caused no harm but apparently they did make a difference because I did try your provided components definition without strings earlier but that just kept throwing a compilation error. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65959272/2185093) for more about import/export syntax